# Copy and Past NamedRange/Whole Line

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, paste

I've been using the script below to copy and paste all previous rows in an inserted row before on Google Sheets.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('20:20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('21:21').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('L20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('H20').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};
```

As I will have insertions below each other, whenever I use the top ones will change the line to be copied to the others. I would like to remove dependency on expression ('20:20'), and a think that NamedRange is the way.

Is it possible to copy the values of a whole row or named range in one sheet and paste them in the same sheet, just creating a line above?

Comment: Can you make a simple sample spreadsheet with multiple sheets, showing what is happening and what you would like to happen?

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TUv_c5zyiYJPHqM8mtS_Qd_z869elwwHCXDEMjs7g70/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TUv_c5zyiYJPHqM8mtS_Qd_z869elwwHCXDEMjs7g70/edit?usp=sharing)_italic_ **bold** `code`. @CodeCamper The 'plus' image start the script, specific for each part. The second need to 'understand' when the first included a row, to insert in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Porperties Service [1] you can fix your problem, I edited the code linked to your example Spreadsheet as follows:

```
function PlusMP() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('5:5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('6:6').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('L5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('H5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  //Set offset property
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var offset = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('offset'));

  if ( offset == null) {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('offset', 1);
  }
  else {
    scriptProperties.setProperty('offset', offset + 1);
  }
};

function PlusCOMP() {
  //Get offset property
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var offset = Number(scriptProperties.getProperty('offset'));

  if(offset == null) {
    offset = 0;
  }
  var row = 10 + offset;
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange(row + ':' + row).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange(row + ':' + row).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('L' + row).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('H' + row).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
};

function resetOffset() {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('offset', 0);
}
```

When the PlusMP function is run it'll set or update the `offset` property, and when PlusCOMP function is run it'll use the same `offset` property to insert the rows accordingly.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties

Comment: Thank you so much, but, in this way, resulted 'Range not found'.

Comment: What line and when you're doing what?

Comment: The first image/button, PlusMP and the second Plus Comp are working, but, when I execute PlusMP, PlusComp stop working, resulting 'Range not found'.

Comment: I fixed it, the offset is being returned as a string and it needed to be changed to a number. Also, I added a resetOffset function in case you need it.